# É possível subir aplicações blazor webassembly com .net core hospetado no Herokuapp via docker?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker, blazor

Quando vou subir uma aplicação blazor server, eu utilizo os seguintes passos:

- Crio um arquivo dockerfile na mesma pasta onde está o projeto assim:

  `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base`

  `WORKDIR /app`

  `COPY . .`

  `CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet NomeAplicativo.dll`

Abro cmd na pasta do projeto e dou os comandos;

- `dotnet publish -c release`
- `heroku container:login`
- `docker build -t {nome do aplicativo heroku} {caminho da pasta publish (com duas barras em vez de uma\\)}`
- `docker tag {nome do aplicativo heroku}`
- `docker tag {nome do aplicativo heroku} registry.heroku.com/{nome do aplicativo heroku}/web`
- `docker push registry.heroku.com/{nome do aplicativo heroku}/web`
- `heroku container:release web --app {nome do aplicativo heroku}`

E pronto! Meu app está rodando tranquilamente no heroku. Assim como esse http://selesgabriel.herokuapp.com

Antes de começar a realizar os passos, eu copio o mesmo arquivo docker para a pasta onde está o publish e só assim dou início aos docker build

Mas quando tento fazer o mesmo para blazor webassembly com .netcore hospedado, não funciona, ao dar o comando 'docker run -p 8124:80 testeblazorapp' no cmd dentro da pasta publish para ver se o app está funcionando normalmente, assim como acontece no blazor server, ele dá a seguinte msg:

> > It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
> > Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
> > https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Procurei bastante, mas não consegui encontrar nada. E ao abrir o app heroku aparece aquela msg como se não tivesse nenhum site nele, e quando rodo o comando 'docker run -p 8124:80 testeblazorapp', ele dá a msg conforme na msg que coloquei abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esqueci de uma coisa, antes de começar a realizar os passos, eu copio o mesmo arquivo docker para a pasta onde está o publish e só assim dou início aos docker build.....

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque também qual a mensagem de erro que aparece.

Comment: Obrigado! Coloquei mais informações lá

Comment: Como o projeto foi criado? No Visual Studio, selecionando a opção `Blazor WebAssembly App` (sem marcar `ASP.NET Core hosted)? Ou linha de comando com `dotnet new blazorwasm`? Ou de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Acebei de notar que vc diz `webassembly com .netcore hospedado`. Neste caso, penso que o projeto foi criado no Visual Studio com `Blazor WebAssembly App` e vc **marcou** a opção ASP.NET Core hosted. Certo?

Comment: Eu criei no visual studio mesmo. E esse procedimento eu fiz tanto com a opção ASP.NET Core hosted marcado e também com a opção desmarcada. Ambas não dão certo.